# Спрятать показать комментарии в Eclipse IDEA среда разработки

Tags: eclipse, java, intellij-idea

Есть ли функция спрятать/показать комментарии в какой-либо среде разработки на java? И если есть, то как ей пользоваться.

Answer (score 1):

Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Folding

[Any way to hide comments in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346859/any-way-to-hide-comments-in-eclipse)